# Play Framework will not precompile or build a WAR file correctly

Tags: playframework

I checked out a Play application from SVN onto our Ubuntu production server.  I've gotten rid of the .svn files (since Play has issues interacting with them), but whenever I try to run the precompiler or the war functions, I get continuous File Not Found exceptions pointing at "/home/USER/PROJECT/precompiled/..".

I've made a brand new test project alongside it (same root directory and all) and that precompiles and builds its war file with no problem at all.

Anyone have any ideas what I could be missing?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stupid as it sounds, the issues was permissions related.  The user I was in under was not a super user.  When I switched to root, I was able to compile and build accordingly.  I wish the log files had reflected this.